# Java - Return two dimensional array value

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I want to return all values of 2D array. How I can return it if I use get method with String type?

```
public class Data {
private final String[][] table;
public Data(){
    table = new String[][] {{"ID", "NAME"},
                         {"101", "A"},
                         {"102", "B"},
                         {"103", "C"},
                         {"104", "D"},
                         {"105", "E"}};
}

public String[][] get(){
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
            table[i][j] = table[i][j];
        }
    }
    return table;
}

public void displayMessage(){
    System.out.println(get());
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you write `table[i][j] = table[i][j]`? The entire `get` method can be reduced into `return table`...

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Where's the problem? You're already returning the array from `get()`. What bugs me is that needless iteration inside the method though. And what you're probably getting at is the output of `System.out.println(get());`.  You'll probably get is something like `[[Ljava.lang.String;@1db9742` and you want the array content printed, right?

Comment: Question is not clear. What are you trying to get as output?

Comment: I want to print out all the values

Comment: @MarkMartin: one item at each line? Or one line per "*row*"?

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(get()));`

Comment: If you want to print the elements line by line try iterating over the first dimension and call `System.out.println( Arrays.toString( table[i] ) );`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem One line/row

Comment: @Thomas How if I won't to use Arrays.toString ?

Comment: `for (String[] row : table) System.out.println(Arrays.stream(row).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));`

Comment: Well then use what Andreas suggested or use nested loops and either build a string that's printed at the end or call `System.out.print()` etc. as you iterate.